# Velocity template fails to render because one of the string variable contains a $ character

Tags: java, spring, velocity

```
 "name": "$data"
```

I am using velocity with Java and if the value of `$data` contains a `$` character like `$abcd` then the template fails to render because of the error message.

```
"Error rendering the template ::: HomePage : data [abcd, abcd] is missing"
```

How to fix this issue so I can render strings with `$` character in them?

Also, tried the escape tool in java but nothing seems to work.

**Edit**: I have a user object coming from BE and I want to render different values for this user like `$user.name`, `$user.address`, etc.
If any field say `$user.name` is `abcd$pqr` then parsing fails because of unknown variable `$pqr`.
How to fix this issue when we have to render the data nested in object?
If I do the following

```
#set($username = "$user.name")
"name": "$username"
```

then it fails with error that `$user.name` is missing and treats it as one and doesn't interpolate.
Basically, I want to show the value of `$user.name` intact.

Answer (score 0):

When defining values for Velocity, you can just use single quotes to avoid interpolation:

```
#set( $data = '$data' )
"name": "$data"
```

Or use a specific variable to display `$`:

```
#set( $d = '$' )
"name": "${d}data"
```

Or use a comment:

```
#* this is a comment *#
"name": "$#**#data"
```

Or use unparsed content:

```
"name": #[["$data"]]#
```

Comment: this doesn't work, still the same issue.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I thought you were declaring a Velocity Map, sorry.

Comment: I have updated the question, can you check again please?

Comment: Did you check the generated output? Because it should be good. I'm inclined to think that the problem comes from an #eval() directive somewhere else. Without #eval, Velocity has no real reason to interpolate the content of a variable. Only literals are evaluated.

Comment: The template is still failing because of the unknown variable velocity gets. $pqr in this case. Any way to fix this or do I need to clean the request before rendering the view.

Comment: If I test your example, `#set($username = '$user.name') "name": "$username"`, it works for me. Do you have some kind of registered ReferenceInsertionHandler that would evaluate again variables content? There is a double evaluation somewhere, your problem is hard to solve without knowing where it is located. Do you see stacktraces?

Comment: Hey, can you try with double quotes, I updated in the example.

Comment: Let me paraphrase Velocity documentation: inside a Velocity expression (on the right hand side of a `#set` expression for instance), double quotes are interpolated, single quotes are not. Outside a Velocity expression, everything is interpolated, Velocity interprets the quotes as being part of the surrounding text.
So in the given example, the error message is normal since you are trying to interpolate the string `"$user.name"`, whereas `$user.name` doesn't exist.